# Accessing returned data in java(used in tic tac toe)

Tags: java, return, tic-tac-toe

Now how do i use the return to determine a winner. I use 8 of these statements for each of the possible winning possibilities. This ends the game after the first move, why and what would work?

```
 if(grid[1][1].equals(grid[1][2]) && grid[1][2].equals(grid[1][3]))
        {
            done = true;//makes game over by making done true
        }
        //later returns done
```

Comment: Assign the result of the test function to a variable like that `int result = test(x, y);`

Comment: Just search "java example" or something and try to understand what the example is doing and how.

Comment: Guessing and asking questions when the guess does not work is an inefficient way to learn a programming language. I suggest working through a beginning Java book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

```
int z = 1;
test(x,y);
```

Throws away the result, the z inside of test is in a local scope. You want

```
z = test(x,y);
System.out.println(z);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this will help me, i am making a tic tac toe game and need to access a returned variable for determining a winner.

Comment: I determine a winnner through  if(grid[1][1].equals(grid[1][2]) && grid[1][2].equals(grid[1][3]))
        {
            done = true;//makes game over by making done true
        }

Comment: Then you need to return "done" and set it outside the method. boolean winner = checkWinner(). Or you can have the winner as a field in your class in which case you can set it from any member methods or any methods that has a reference to an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

This code will compile even in this shape, as you wrote. But you dont passed value of method test anywhere, so it is redundant code. You have to declare variable and passed a value of test method to it. for example `int veryImportanatValue = test(x,y);`

Answer (score 0):

you need a clearer understanding of global and local variables.

here, z is a local variable in main method, and another z is another local variable in your test method. they are totally different expect that they share the same name.

what you can do is to assign the return value to some local variable in your main method (the method form where you call the test method) and then do your computation with the variable you have assigned the value to.